# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable when using `df = DataFrame()`

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have a Streamlit application which uses Pandas dataframes to show graphs in Altair.

I've exhausted most likely causes but I still get the following errors.

At first the error was showing up with my code:

```
  File "/mnt/c/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/deps/charts/charts.py", line 131, in show_financial_metrics_competitors_chart
    combined_df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

So to fix this, I changed `combined_df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()` to `combined_df = None` even though it seems the former is valid syntax.

The errors went away until errors showed for dependent libraries:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
...
  File "/mnt/c/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style_render.py", line 1957, in Tooltips
    tooltips: DataFrame = DataFrame(),
```

I've been trying a couple days now to figure out the root cause.  I've tried:

- Downgrade to Python3.8 -> same issue
- Upgrade to Python10 -> same issue
- Check source data is valid and populating the DataFrames -> can confirm data eventually fills these DataFrames
- Delete `env/` and reinstall requirements.txt -> did this for every change in Python version and a dozen times more

Here are my versions of key dependencies:

- Python 3.9.2
- pandas==2.0.3
- streamlit==1.29.0
- numpy==1.25.2
- matplotlib==3.7.2

Given the latest error, I'm thinking it's not my code but some version of a dependency which is the root cause.  The strangest thing is my versions for Python or deps have not changed and this has started happening the in last week.

Comment: Try putting `from __future__ import annotations`. I think there was an issue with the union operator in Python 3.9 or something.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs, i think you must provide initial data to use DataFrame():

> Along with the data, you can optionally pass index (row labels) and
> columns (column labels) arguments. If you pass an index and / or
> columns, you are guaranteeing the index and / or columns of the
> resulting DataFrame. Thus, a dict of Series plus a specific index will
> discard all data not matching up to the passed index.

Try creating your data dict first and then calling the class.

```
d = {
     "one": pd.Series([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], index=["a", "b", "c"]),
     "two": pd.Series([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], index=["a", "b", "c", "d"]),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[Source: Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#basics-dataframe)